# Replacing entire string in CSV

Tags: python, string, csv

When I run this code to edit my CSV file, only part of the string gets replaced even if I have the string in my dictionary.

```
import re

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

bottle = "vial jug canteen urn jug33"
transport = "car automobile airplane scooter"

mydict = {}
for word in bottle.split():
    mydict[word] = 'bottle'
for word in transport.split():
    mydict[word] = 'transport'
print(mydict) # test


with open('replacesample.csv','r') as f:
    text=f.read()
    text=replace_all(text,mydict)
    text=re.sub(r'PROD\s(?=[1-9])',r'PROD',text)

with open('file2.csv','w') as w:
    w.write(text)
```

For example if my strting CSV is this:

```
jug 
canteen 
urn
car
automobile
swag
airplane
jug33
```

My final ends up being:

```
bottle 
bottle 
bottle
transport
transport
swag
transport
bottle33
```

How do I fix this?

**Expected:**

```
bottle 
bottle 
bottle
transport
transport
swag
transport
bottle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a dictionary to enumerate your replacement patterns. Dictionaries return keys and values in arbitrary ordering.

As such, the `jug` -> `bottle` replacement takes place *before* the `jug33` -> `bottle` replacement. This replacement works for partial words too.

The solution would be to sort the keys in reverse order of length to ensure that longer matches are replaced first:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in sorted(dic.iteritems(), key=lambda i: len(i[0]), reverse=True):
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
```

Demo:

```
>>> def replace_all(text, dic):
...     for i, j in dic.iteritems():
...         text = text.replace(i, j)
...     return text
... 
>>> replace_all('jug33 jug', mydict)
'bottle33 bottle'
>>> def replace_all(text, dic):
...     for i, j in sorted(dic.iteritems(), key=lambda i: len(i[0]), reverse=True):
...         text = text.replace(i, j)
...     return text
... 
>>> replace_all('jug33 jug', mydict)
'bottle bottle'
```

Comment: What would I do if in my CSV,there are strings I want to leave alone but start in the same way as some of the strings I want to change. For example, what would I do if `jugular` was in my csv but I wanted to leave it alone?

Comment: You then either have to strip your lines (remove whitespace) and test for dictionary membership (so loop over lines first), or use regular expressions with`\b` word boundaries.